# How can I get a 4th wire(ground) for a hot tub from a 3 wire run

Tags: subpanel

I have a 4 wire hot tub coming and I have a run of 3 wires ran to the hot tub location from a sub panel(2 hot 1 neutral). My question is, can I use a grounding rod at the hot tub disconnect to supply me with the missing "4th" wire/ground for the hot tub?

Comment: Are these 3 wires by chance in metal conduit?

Comment: Do you really have "2 hot 1 neutral", or do you have a /2 run of "Romex" cable with 2 insulated wires and 1 uninsulated *Ground* wire?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the hot tub disconnect/end of run junction box, as well as the inside of the subpanel please?

Comment: Even if the wire is run in PVC conduit, that would make pulling a ground easy. That's why people are asking for pictures. You're smart enough to know that you don't know quite what you're doing and have done the right thing by asking. Provide the info the knowledgeable people here need and you'll get _very_ knowledgeable answers!

Comment: I did not get notifies of replies so I am just now seeing your responses. Not home to get pics as of now. The sub panel the 3 wires are ran from are as follows: GFCI CB in panel the 3 wires are coming from this CB and being ran 80,(#6 in liquid tight) They are terminated at the hot tub location. I have 2 hots and a neutral with these 2 wires, not 2 hot and a ground. I will add a GFCI at the tub location. This is where i wanted to know if i could add the grounding rod and that would provide the ground for the tub.

Comment: @Jason - need clarity here - you say you have a neutral - how do you know it's a neutral? Is is a separately insulated (probably white) wire? Are your 3 wires actually 3 individual completely separate wires running in a conduit, or are they bundled together in a 'Romex' style cable? I'm asking because it *really does make a difference*!

Comment: Yes there are 3 individual wires that are #6 THHN coming from a sub panel to the hot tub location. 2 hots and a neutral in liquid tight conduit. The plan was to run a ground at the tub for the ground. The person that ran them said using a ground at the tub would be fine. After the hot tub salesman repeatedly saying wiring was an issue all the time it led me to do some reading and now I want to make sure it’s good. I plan to put a cutoff at the tub in line if site.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not! And hot tub wiring is [nothing to fool around with!](https://www.cnn.com/2016/08/11/us/california-valley-fire-faulty-hot-tub/index.html)  Anytime you have water and electricity near each other, you create a potential killer.

This is the worst possible place to cut corners on the grounding. The Electrical Code specifically forbids an ungrounded feed to a hot tub.

It is possible that your 3-wire run to *the old* hot tub is actually 2 hots + a **ground wire**.  Neutral is never bare*.    Many 240V appliances (water heater, air conditioner, EVSE) don't require neutral at all.  They can use 3-wire runs with a bare or green ground wire, and 2 hots.

If that's all news to you, [this video talks about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4) at 11:39.

If your new hot tub needs neutral, then you will need a 4-wire connection.  **You will also need a 2-pole/240V GFCI breaker in the supply panel, which needs to be a certain distance away from the hot tub**.  If the nearby sub panel is too close, put the GFCI breaker in the main panel that feeds the sub panel.

---

---

---

---

* That is often an area for novice confusion, because they see with their own eyes one of two things: First the **service entrance** wires coming from the utility, which do not have ground and do have neutral.  They often have a bare neutral.  Second, *older* pre-1996 dryer and range circuits were allowed to be wired hot-hot-neutral ungrounded, and they were allowed to use SE (Service Entrance) type cable, which had a bare neutral.  However that was not allowed on any other appliance, and was banned in 1996 because the presumption of safety was disproven.

Hot tubs have *never* been allowed to be wired 3-wire hot-hot neutral.   *Though, just between you, me and the ground rod, there's not much danger **if the whole circuit is GFCI protected** from the sub panel*. Which it should be anyway, because that is a Code requirement, and it makes so many hazards simply go away.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have 2 hots and a neutral behind a 240 gfci. I do not have the ground running from the sub panel to the hot tub location. i will put a gfci at the tub 5' away and wanted to add the grounding rod at the tub with the new gfci.

Comment: @Jason it won't help stack two GFCIs on top of one another.   Ground rod doesn't help a whole lot.  Ideal thing is to **retrofit a ground wire**, which is legal if the original installation was.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. By retro you mean run a ground from the sub panel to the tub location?